# F'(x)=2|x|. What is the graph of f(x).

Tags: calculus, derivatives, absolute-value

I have been told that f(x) would look like this:

y+0.5=x^2 for x>0

y-0.5=-x^2 for x<0

With two holes at x=0 (no point exists there.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmBxY.png

I thought because dy/dx has a value at x=0, and f(x) is not differentiable at x=0, this should be false. Would this be disproven by the logic that because dy/dx is not differentiable at x=0, this is the correct f(x) for dy/dx? It would be optimal if this could be answered / confirmed *without* the use of integrals.

Comment: $F(x) = x|x|+c$ does the job for any constant $c$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $F(x) = F(0)+\int_0^x F'(t) dt = F(0)+\int_0^x |t| dt = \begin{cases}  F(0)+{x^2 \over 2}, & x \ge 0 \\ F(0)-{x^2 \over 2}, & x < 0 \end{cases}$.

Simplifying gives $F(x) = F(0) + {1 \over 2} x |x|$.

Comment: I believe the question was written incorrectly to begin with, but I have modified (f'(x) = 2|x|) it in order for there to be a possible answer. How about now, would this still be the graph of f(x)? If not, can you please give me a good way to explain why? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If a function is not continuous at a point, it cannot be differentiable there. If $F'(x) = 2|x|$ (I have $x$ above, but that's just a factor of $2$), then implicitly $F$ must be continuous, which the picture is not.

Comment: That was my reasoning as well, however, I was told that because dy/dx is not differentiable at x=0, it is valid for f(x) to be discontinuous at x=0. I was not able to understand this.

Comment: In the above case $F'$ is continuous at $x=0$, so I'm not sure what relevance that has?

Comment: It was that despite F' being continuous at x=0,  it is not differentiable there (cusp). Therefore, once again, it is valid for f(x) to be discontinuous at x=0. This may be incorrect, my reasoning was that this only applies to F''

Comment: Just the existence of $F'(0)$ is all that is needed to ensure that $F$ is continuous at $x=0$.